# File-->New-->Wizard doesn't show up the Android project post installation

Tags: android, eclipse

I have installed ADT 11.0.0 plugin for Eclipse on top of 3.6.2 classic. The plug-in installation was fine.

Android DDMS, Android Development Tools, Android Hierarchy Viewer, Android TraceView

But `File-->New-->Wizard` doesn't show up the Android project, what could be wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to manually upload the plug-in files to get past this error, none of the above options worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked under Other?

I have my Android Project under File->New->Other

Or Just ctrl+N

Answer (score 0):

If restarting Eclipse doesn't work, you may have to reinstall Eclipse and the plugin.

Comment: I have done that twice already, since all the Android plugins are there not sure what could be wrong with my installation.